# How to set and get people picker fields of a list using REST API?

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

How to set and get people picker fields of a list using REST API

Comment: i have tried set and get using jsom in content editor webpart i'm able to get and set the values but the only issue is with executequeryasync the methods which im calling are jumbling

Answer (score 4):

To get people field try below code:

```
//Here users is a people of group field
var users = [];
$.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('employees')/items?$select=Users/Title,Users/Id,Users/EMail,Users/FirstName,Users/LastName,Users/EMail&$expand=Users",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            var items = data.d.results;
            if (items.length > 0) {
                for (var i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
                    var firstname, lastname, email, name, profileId, profileLink = "";
                    name = items[i].Users.Title;
                    if (name != undefined) {
                        firstname = items[i].Users.FirstName;
                        lastname = items[i].Users.LastName;
                        email = items[i].Users.EMail;
                        name = items[i].Users.Title;
                        profileId = items[i].Users.Id;
                        profileLink = "/sites/YourSiteCollection/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?ID=" + profileId;

                        users.push({
                            "title": title,
                            "name" : name,
                            "firstname" : firstname,
                            "lastname" : lastname,
                            "email" : email,
                            "profileId" : profileId,
                            "profileLink" : profileLink
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
  });
```

To use the values from the array:

```
function useValues() {
    var html = "<table>"
    for (var i=0; i < users.length; i++) {
        var name = users[i].name;
        var profileLink = users[i].profileLink;
        var email = users[i].email;
        html += "<tr><td><a href='" + profileLink + "'>" + name + "</a></td></tr>";
        html += "<tr><td><a href='mailto:" + email + "'>" + email + "</a></td></tr>";
    }
    html += "</table>";
    return html;
}
```

To add the item, try it as below:

```
//Create a item
var itemProperties = {
    '__metadata' : { 'type': 'SP.Data.employeesListItem' },
    'Title': 'Test',
    'Users' : { 'results': [_spPageContextInfo.userId] } //add current user 
};


$.ajax({       
       url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('employees')/items",   
       type: "POST",   
       processData: false,  
       contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
       data: JSON.stringify(itemProperties),
       headers: {   
          "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
          "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
       },
       success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
       },
       error:function(data){
            console.log(data);
       }
    });
```

Reference - [add value to people field 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500077/how-to-add-user-to-sharepoint-list-item-user-field-using-rest-api-in-sp2013)

Answer (score 3):

**To get value of People Picker using REST API**

**URL**: `SiteURL + /_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List Display Name')/items$expand=Author&$select=Author/Id,Title`

**Author**: People Picker column in list

**To Set value in People Picker field in form**

You will need user email or login name and use below code

```
var divPeople = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.PeoplePickerDiv_TopSpan;
//PeoplePickerDiv_TopSpan - Specify the unique ID of the DOM element where the picker will render.

var userObj = { 'Key': "sample@sample.com" };

divPeople.AddUnresolvedUser(userObj, true);
```

**To set value People picker field in list using REST API**

```
var addNewItemUrl = "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('SpTest')/Items"; 

var data = {
    __metadata: { 'type': 'SP.Data.SpTestListItem' },
    AuthorId: 3,
};

addNewItem(addNewItemUrl,data);

function addNewItem(url, data) {
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + url,
        type: "POST",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
}
```

**Note: For multi value people picker column pass int array inside people piker field.**

EDIT: `URL: SiteURL + /_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List Display Name')/items$expand=Author&$select=Author/Id,Title` There should be a "?" after /items

```
URL: SiteURL + /_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List Display Name')/items?$expand=Author&$select=Author/Id,Title
```